# How to Apply and Revert Magento Patches in localhost?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

How do I apply and revert Magento Patches on Windows localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On stackoverflow this question was answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29930111/387136

Quote from the answer

> 1) My windows has sh.exe available and can run .sh files - just type
>   it into the command line, git bash works fine too. UPDATE: my sh.exe
>   was likely installed along with git. It is relatively easy to install
>   though.
>
> 2) On windows machines you may need to edit the PATCH-... file. Find
>   the CURRENT_DIR=`$PWD_BIN`/ line. Since you will be running it from
>   the magento root directory anyway this can be left blank. Go ahead and
>   remove everything after the equals sign. It should now read
>   CURRENT_DIR=. See here for an explanation.
>
> 3)Now just move the file into your magento root directory and run it.

Comment: Thenk you sander Mangel